# Django TabularInline override admin temaplate

Tags: python, django

I have a class that inherits from TabularInline. I have overridden the template, how do I pass data to this template to output it?

```
class commercial_proposal_productadmin(SortableTabularInline):

    model = commercial_proposal_product
    extra = 0
    template = "admin/tabular.html"
```

i tried to use the change_view function, but the world value is not displayed in the template

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = {'world':'hello'}
        return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The template code is required. But in order to display something in the template, it is necessary to output data from the context with a special tag of the Django template engine:

```
{{ world }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/